# Why does changing one bound property seem to affect another?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've set up a custom object called `Model`, and it has two bindable properties. One of them looks like this:

```
Private _activeCompanies As List(Of company)
Public Event activeCompaniesChanged As EventHandler
Public Property activeCompanies() As List(Of company)
    Get
        Return Me._activeCompanies
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of company))
        Me._activeCompanies = value
        'raise the event so databinding is notified
        RaiseEvent activeCompaniesChanged(Me, New EventArgs)
    End Set
End Property
```

The other one is exactly the same, except it's `activeContracts`.

I then add `Model` as a data source to my project. I then drag `activeCompanies` to one DataGridView, and `activeContracts` to another.

I have a button that changes `model.activeContracts`. When the property changes, the second DataGridView correctly updates itself; but the first DGV, tied only to `model.activeCompanies`, also gets 'selected'. Its current cell changes. It doesn't change the row, but it does actually trigger a change event on the ActiveContractsBindingSource (that was automatically created when I dragged the property onto the DGV).

This is causing problems for me, because I'm trying to use the events to trigger updates to data elsewhere in the application. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Types which use mutable objects (like a `List<T>`) to encapsulate state should generally avoid exposing reference to those objects to anything which might mutate them.  It's unclear whether you are intending `_activeCompanies` to encapsulate the identity of a `List<T>` owned by outside code, or to encapsulate the contents of the list, but in neither case will your code be notified when the *contents* of the list change.

Comment: I was hoping to use the `activeCompaniesChanged` event to notify the rest of my code when the contents change.

Comment: @SamSelikoff: I've not used it, but you might need to look `ObservableXX` classes; I think there's an `ObservableCollection<T>` that might suit your purposes.